# Short survey on Enterprise JavaBeans usage

Tags: ejb

I would be very appreciative if anyone who has any experience with using Enterprise JavaBeans, or who considered, but rejected the use of EJBs would respond to a short survey. The survey consists of eleven (11) questions, and should take five (5) minutes or less to complete.

I am collecting this data for a class that I am taking.

The URL for the survey is http://cs.createsurvey.com/c/89/9089/survey/11793-UCyRqE.html

Thank you very much in advance for your participation!

Regards,

Tom Harris

Comment: Seems fair that you post the results back on this site